# I am trying to post a java object to a .net core web api.But I need to post object arrays in java

Tags: java, javafx

So I am trying to do a form post from Java. To my .net core webapi.  The form post was working very well not until I added a requirement of sending an array  of a inner object. I want to believe that when I do my post my .net is not understanding the payload that it recieving. So the java code below sends values to .net core.  After the Models that is suppose to collect (bind) the request from java code is also pasted

//This method is going to post values to .net

```
public  <T> T  Handlepost(File inFile,Productmodel model,final Class<T> objectClass)  {

    FileInputStream fis = null;

    try {
                    StringBody name = new StringBody(model.getName());
                    StringBody barcode = new StringBody(model.getBarcode());
                    StringBody quantity = new StringBody(model.getStockQuantity()+"");
                    StringBody unitcost = new StringBody(model.getUnitCost()+"");            
                    StringBody discountamt = new StringBody(model.getDiscountamt()+"");
                    StringBody describe = new StringBody(model.getDescription());
                    StringBody companyid = new StringBody(model.getCompanyID()+"");
                    StringBody unitid = new StringBody(model.getUnit().getID());
                    StringBody inventorycatid = new StringBody(model.getProductposcategory().getID());

                    String hascolors = "";
                    if(model.getHascolortypes()){
                        hascolors = "yes";
                    }
                    else
                        hascolors = "no";

                    StringBody hascolortypes = new StringBody(hascolors);

                    if(inFile != null){
        fis = new FileInputStream(inFile);
                    }
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());


                    String Posturl = urlobject.Createproducturl();
        // server back-end URL
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Posturl); //"http://localhost:56175/api/product/create"
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

        // set the file input stream and file name as arguments
                    if(inFile != null)
        entity.addPart("Image", new InputStreamBody(fis, inFile.getName()));


                    entity.addPart("Name", name);
                    entity.addPart("Barcode",barcode);
                    entity.addPart("StockQuantity", quantity);
                    entity.addPart("UnitCost", unitcost);
                    entity.addPart("Discountamt", discountamt);
                    entity.addPart("Description", describe);
                    entity.addPart("CompanyID", companyid);
                    entity.addPart("Unit.ID",unitid);
                    entity.addPart("Hascolortypes", hascolortypes);
                    entity.addPart("InventorycategoryID",inventorycatid);

                   // Gson gson = new Gson();
                  /*  String json  = new JSONArray(model.getCostpersizes()).toString(); //gson.toJson(model.getCostpersizes());

                    StringBody productprices = new StringBody(json);                     
                     entity.addPart("Costpersizes", productprices);*/
```

//This is the array of the inner object. I use it to collect multiple selections from my users. So I have to send an array of an object within my payload to my .net controller.

```
                //Adding array to the Product post object
               if(model.getCostpersizes() != null ){
                    for(int k=0; k<model.getCostpersizes().size(); k++){
                        Productpricemodel pricemodel = model.getCostpersizes().get(k);                              

                        entity.addPart("Costpersizes[].SN", new StringBody(pricemodel.getSN()));
                        entity.addPart("Costpersizes[].ProductID", new StringBody(pricemodel.getProductID()));
                        entity.addPart("Costpersizes[].AvailableQuantity", new StringBody(pricemodel.getAvailableQuantity()+""));
                         entity.addPart("Costpersizes[].Barcode", new StringBody(pricemodel.getBarcode()));

                             entity.addPart("Costpersizes[].Cost", new StringBody(pricemodel.getCost()+""));
                             entity.addPart("Costpersizes[].Size.ID", new StringBody(pricemodel.getSize().getID())); 
                             entity.addPart("Costpersizes[].Response", new StringBody(pricemodel.getResponse()));
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println("This is the string reprensentaion of the object that was sent to the server");
                    System.out.println(entity.toString());

        httppost.setEntity(entity);

                    httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    httppost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

                       if(Main.LicenseToken != null){
                            httppost.setHeader("Authorization",Main.LicenseToken);  //I just added this here
                       }

        // execute the request
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        HttpEntity responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                    /*
        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity, "UTF-8");

        System.out.println("[" + statusCode + "] " + responseString);*/

        if (responseEntity != null) {
                            InputStream inputStream = responseEntity.getContent();
                            Header contentEncoding = httpResponse.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
                            if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                                inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(inputStream);
                            }

                            String resultString = convertStreamToString(inputStream);

                            System.out.println("output     "+resultString);
                            inputStream.close();
                            return new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(resultString, objectClass);
                    }            

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        System.err.println("Unable to make connection");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Unable to read file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
            finally {
        try {
            if (fis != null) fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }

            return null;
}


    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("first "+e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    } finally {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("second  "+e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

}

The problem with the code above is am trying to send an array of an inner object. This part of the code above is what is giving me problems,

```
  //Adding array to the Product post object
                   if(model.getCostpersizes() != null ){
                        for(int k=0; k<model.getCostpersizes().size(); k++){
                            Productpricemodel pricemodel = model.getCostpersizes().get(k);                              

                            entity.addPart("Costpersizes[].SN", new StringBody(pricemodel.getSN()));
                            entity.addPart("Costpersizes[].ProductID", new StringBody(pricemodel.getProductID()));
                            entity.addPart("Costpersizes[].AvailableQuantity", new StringBody(pricemodel.getAvailableQuantity()+""));
                             entity.addPart("Costpersizes[].Barcode", new StringBody(pricemodel.getBarcode()));
                             entity.addPart("Costpersizes[].Cost", new StringBody(pricemodel.getCost()+""));
                             entity.addPart("Costpersizes[].Size.ID", new StringBody(pricemodel.getSize().getID())); 
                             entity.addPart("Costpersizes[].Response", new StringBody(pricemodel.getResponse()));
                        }
                    }
```

Here is my .net model obect that I use to collect values posted to the form

```
 public class Product
{ 
    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }

    public OptionSelect Unit { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Barcode { get; set; }  //This is code is used to prove originality of the product

    public int StockQuantity { get; set; }

    public double UnitCost { get; set; }

    public int Discountamt { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int CompanyID { get; set; }

    // public List<OptionSelect> Producttags { get; set; }

    public string Hascolortypes { get; set; }

    public List<Productpricemodel> Costpersizes { get; set; }

    public string InventorycategoryID { get; set; }
}

 public class Productpricemodel
{
    [JsonProperty("sn")]
    public string SN { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("cost")]
    public float Cost { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("productID")]
    public string ProductID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("size")]
    public OptionSelect Size { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("availablequantity")]
    public double AvailableQuantity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("barcode")]
    public string Barcode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("response")]
    public string Response { get; set; }
}
```

So please how do I post into

```
public List<Productpricemodel> Costpersizes { get; set; }
```

From Java. Posting a Array inner object. been sweating for days now.

Comment: I don't understand after reading through it. Please add more comments into your code, explaining the **intended and unintended** behavior.

Comment: @FailingCoder I edited the code. If it is still complicated kindly let me know. added a few more comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct. There a null pointer string. the string description was not passed from the GUI interface. This lead to the error.

Costpersizes[] value also was changed to Costpersizes[k].
Needed to pass an index so the api would be able to differentiate rows in the array.